# Rethink merge array

Tags: rethinkdb, array-merge, reql

I have a query -

```
 r.table('orgs')
        .filter(function(org) {
            return r.expr(['89a26384-8fe0-11e8-9eb6-529269fb1459', '89a26910-8fe0-11e8-9eb6-529269fb1459'])
            .contains(org('id'));
        })
        .pluck("users")
```

This returns following output-

```
{
"users": [
"3a415919-f50b-4e15-b3e6-719a2a6b26a7"
]
} {
"users": [
"d8c4aa0a-8df6-4d47-8b0e-814a793f69e2"
]
}
```

How do I get the result as -

```
[
 "3a415919-f50b-4e15-b3e6-719a2a6b26a7","d8c4aa0a-8df6-4d47-8b0e-814a793f69e2"
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't use that complicated and resource-consuming `.filter` directly on a table. Since your tested field is already indexed (`id`), you can:

```
r.table('orgs').getAll('89...59', '89...59')
```

or

```
r.table('orgs').getAll(r.args(['89...59', '89...59']))
```

which is way faster (way!). I recently found [this article](https://medium.com/connect-the-dots/optimizing-queries-in-rethinkdb-584d7f660cb) about how faster that is.

Now to get an array of `users` without the wrapping, using the [brackets](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/bracket/) operation:

```
r.table('orgs').getAll(...).pluck('users')('users')
```

will provide a result like

```
[
  '123',
  '456'
],
[
  '123',
  '789'
]
```

We just removed the `"users"` wrapping, but the result is an array of arrays. Let's flatten this 2D array with [`.concatMap`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/concat_map/):

```
r.table('orgs').getAll(...).pluck('users')('users').concatMap(function (usrs) {
  return usrs;
})
```

Now we've concatenated the sub-arrays into one, however we see duplicates (from my previous result example, you'd have `'123'` twice). Just [`.distinct`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/distinct/) the thing:

```
r.table('orgs').getAll(...).pluck('users')('users').concatMap(function (usrs) {
  return usrs;
}).distinct()
```

From the example I took, you have now:

```
'123',
'456',
'789'
```

Et voilà!